# TypeError: responseHeaders.getSetCookie is not a function

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to learn more about Next and i'm following a very basic tutorial, but i'm running into a error

When doing a trycatch and made a simple post method, that just works fine when creating the topic, but instead of a 201 status, i receive a 500 status with no message, and in the console, this error shows up:

```
 ⨯ TypeError: responseHeaders.getSetCookie is not a function
    at new ResponseCookies (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/cookies/index.js:213:47)
    at new NextResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:40:22)
    at NextResponse.json (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:67:16)
    at GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/topics/route.js:28:95)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\Micro\Desktop\Study\mongocrud\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62499
```

That's my trycatch connection:

```
const connectMongoDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And that's the post method

```
export async function POST(request){
    const {title, description} = await request.json()
    await connectMongoDB()

    await Topic.create({title, description})

    return NextResponse.json({message: "Topic Created"},{status: 201})
}
```

Seems to be something with next, but i have no idea how to fix it up

Comment: Have you by any chance installed/upgraded to Next v13.5.5? It seems to be a regression causing that error, because multiple devs have reported the same error in different kinds of projects. If so, then downgrading to v13.5.4 should fix the problem for now.

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you

Comment: Would you mind rewriting your entire question that you are getting a `TypeError: responseHeaders.getSetCookie is not a function` error as it's unrelated to Mongo and anything you are doing. I can then post my comment as an answer and we can ensure future users with the same issue can find it easier.

Comment: Sure! I'm kinda new here, but already changed the title and some parts of the question.
Can you post as an answer now? If i need to change something else, just let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TypeError: responseHeaders.getSetCookie is not a function` error has been accidentally introduced in Next 13.5.5 as part of an internal upgrade of the runtime. The framework tries to call `Headers#getSetCookie` which older versions of Node prior to 18.16 don't ship and which isn't polyfilled anymore. As such that was an unintended breaking change.

For now you can either downgrade Next to 13.5.4 or upgrade Node to at least 18.16. The Next team will be reverting that change soon and introduce it again in Next 14 where they plan to bump the minimum required Node version anyways.

Comment: I was using Node 18.4.0, and upgrading to Next 14.0.1 from 13.5.6, was the fix for me.